# Upgrading to OSX High Sierra breaks Terminal hot key functionality

Tags: terminal, keyboard, high-sierra

On Sierra's Terminal <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>2</kbd>, etc. would switch between different Terminal windows.  Now it switches between tabs within the same window.  Yes, I could use <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>`</kbd>to cycle between the windows, however, but I want back the previous functionality.

Comment: Try [iTerm2](https://iterm2.com/). It has that functionality in by default and I use it extensively.  IMO, iTerm2 is a better "Terminal" anyway.

Comment: That might be debatable : https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/iterm2-leaks-everything-you-hover-in-your-terminal-via-dns-requests/

Answer (score 7):

The Terminal settings allow you to escape this hell.

Terminal > Preferences (or Cmd-,) > General:

Second to last item: "Use Cmd-1 through Cmd-9 to switch tabs"

Unselect this option and it all goes back to how it was before!

Comment: I am so grateful.  I completely missed that setting in Terminal.  I was instead trying to figure out how to do the mapping through System Preference -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts (failed) or looking for settings in Terminal -> Preferences -> Profile.

Comment: I was trying the same. Then, somehow, had the glorious idea to search in the settings... et voilà!

Comment: Actually if you have multiple tabs open in window 1 and you are currently in window 2, and switch back to window 1 using `cmd 1` it automatically brings the focus to the first tab in window 1 even if a different tab is forward on window 1.  That is almost equally annoying.

Comment: I noticed that as well. So far I can live with that but I'm considering trying iTerm2.

Comment: I saw this option as well and despite making sure they're unchecked, the behavior is still not the same, as reported by @irritable_phd_syndrom.  Why would Apple's engineers knowingly complicate something that was previous uncomplicated?  Now I have to second-guess all of my keyboard shortcuts in Terminal, which is the application whose shortcut keys I have most committed to motor memory.  It's like learning how to walk all over again.  Die, Apple, die.

Comment: complain here : https://support.apple.com/guide/terminal/keyboard-shortcuts-trmlshtcts/mac